# use zeroinfl with lmer in r

Tags: r, regression, lme4, poisson

I'm trying to merge a `zeroinfl` Poisson regression with a `lmer` model. How can I do that?

```
cro<-zeroinfl(carbapenem~time+COVID-19+time*COVID-19+month+(time|ORGANISM),data=all_mall)
```

This is the error it gives:

```
Error in X1 | ORGANISM : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: You could look at the glmmTMB package; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html

Comment: Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a Bayesian approach with the `brms` package. For example,

```r
brm(carbapenem~time+`COVID-19`+time*`COVID-19`+month+(time|ORGANISM),
    data = all_mall, family = zero_inflated_poisson())
```

Note that to treat COVID-19 as a variable, you should enclose it in back-ticks.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! didn't expect to receive an answer so quickly...This is great help, thank you!!!!!